# IndentationError in python (pygame)

Tags: python

```
if lead_x > randAppleX and lead_x < randAppleX + AppleThickness or lead_x + block_size > randAppleX and lead_x + block_size < randAppleX + AppleThickness:
#   print("x crossover")
   if lead_y > randAppleY and lead_y < randAppleY + AppleThickness:
#    print("x and y crossover")

   elif lead_y + block_size > randAppleY and lead_y + block_size < randAppleY + AppleThickness:

IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

does someone see an error? please help :(

Comment: Uncomment the second print statement and add a statement under the `elif`.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to make a snake game.

Answer (score 0):

Python requires every block to contain at least one statement, and comments are not statements. So, this is syntactically wrong:

```
if lead_y > randAppleY and lead_y < randAppleY + AppleThickness:
    #    print("x and y crossover")
```

For this purpose, use the no-op [`pass` statement](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) when you want e.g. to comment out the single-line block:

```
if lead_y > randAppleY and lead_y < randAppleY + AppleThickness:
    #    print("x and y crossover")
    pass
```